# Iterate list of AWS SQS messages using Mutiny and Quarkus

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

Just getting my head around Mutiny API (and java stream api)...

I have the following code that reads messages off an AWS SQS queue, ref: [quarkus sqs guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts)

```
  Uni<List<Quark>> result =Uni.createFrom()
    .completionStage(sqs.receiveMessage(m -> m.maxNumberOfMessages(10).queueUrl(queueUrl)))
    .onItem().transform(ReceiveMessageResponse::messages)
    .onItem().transform(m -> m.stream().map(Message::body).map(this::toQuark).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Next I want to send each element in the list to a method `handleMessage(Quark quark)`. How do I do this in a "mutiny way!". Do i need to transform again or should not collect..or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you get a `Uni<List<Quark>>`. The Mutiny way would be to transform this into a `Multi` and process each item:

```java
Multi<Quark> multi = result.onItem().transformToMulti(list -> Multi.createFrom().items(list));
```

A Multi is a stream. Each item will be a `Quark`. Then, you just need to do the following:

```java
multi.onItem().invoke(q -> handleMessage(q))
```

I used `invoke` because I don't know what `handleMessage` is doing. If it's processing the Quark and returning something, use `transform`. If it does not return anything, use `invoke`.

BTW, do not forget to subscribe to the returned Multi.